# Android: RestSharp not calling to the server

Tags: android, networking, web-applications, xamarin, restsharp

This problem have wasting me alot of time. I am trying to use the RestSharp to communicate with my Azure web application. I have two project written in Xamarin. First one is the main, Second is testing.

I try both project with the same set of code. The testing project, the communication is working normally. The main project, no matter where I put the code either on a service or simply launching one app, the RestSharp can't communicate with the server. I checked with the Fiddle to see any communication between the device and the server but there was no chase of any communication. I suspect not the RestSharp problem if it was the Second project will have the same problem. Here is my code to call to server.

```
public static void SubmitLog ()
    {
        var appUsage = new AppUsageInfo ();
        appUsage.MAC = "1232";

        ThreadStart action=()=>{
            var serverURL = Application.Context.GetString (Resource.String.url_azure_web);
            var webAPI = Application.Context.GetString (Resource.String.url_usage_log);
            var client = new RestSharp.RestClient (serverURL);
            var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest (webAPI, RestSharp.Method.POST);

            request.Timeout = 1000 * 60;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody (appUsage); 
            Log.Info("Logging", "Server Requesting"); 
            RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
            var content = response.Content; 
            Log.Info ("Testing", "Gallery Response = " + content); 

        };
        Thread thread=new Thread(action){IsBackground=true};
        thread.Start();

    }
```

Comment: do you have internet permissions enabled in your app's manifest?

Comment: Yes I have all the require permission , Access Network State, Wifi, Internet.

Comment: can you reach the server url from the browser on the device/simulator?

Comment: Yes, I have a test project with the same code, and it does give me proper response. I used fiddler to see any request but no request were made.

Comment: Do you mean a unit test project?  Or is it an Android app project?  Are you using the same threading code is both projects?

Comment: Different android app project. I used second one just to test part of the code. The above code is the same on both project.

Comment: Now, I don't use the RestSharp and use the native way HttpClient and now can call to server and get a response back. I have no idea what make it working though. Don't know what RestSharp did.